# Is there any function to separate elements under a given condition in R?

Tags: r

For instance

if I have a data 1:100 and I want to separate those as

elements those are < 25 to group 1

elements those are >=25 and <70 to group 2

rest of them group 3.

Instead of using "if" for each condition, I am wondering is there any function to do that.

Comment: There are other functions, depending on the state your data is in, that will not explicitly use if statements. But in the end you will have to specify which condition needs to apply for each element to be considered group1, 2, or 3. Could you share the input data using dput(<your_data>) and the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can use `cut`, eg below. Run `?cut` for the documentation :)

```
x <- 1:100
# will name it (69,100]. If you're unfamiliar with the notation:
# ( is >
# ) is <
# [ is >=
# ] is <=
cut(x, breaks=c(0, 24, 69, 100))

# edit: if you want to change the levels to groups:
group <- cut(x, breaks=c(0, 24, 69, 100))
levels(group) <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is separate elements to several groups and see the value of element or I should say keep the value of elements. However, 'cut' functions only shows that which group each element belongs to.

Comment: @Sup You can use `split` together with `cut`. For example `split(1:100,cut(1:100, breaks=c(0, 24, 69, 100)))`.